# Error setting up Detox on React-Native/Expo mobile app: "ReferenceError: element is not defined"

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, detox

I am trying to set up end-to-end testing with Detox on a React-Native/Expo mobile app. The app and Jest are currently working fine, but Detox tests give ReferenceError's. I have followed the instructions in this link, https://blog.expo.io/testing-expo-apps-with-detox-and-react-native-testing-library-7fbdbb82ac87, as well as the Detox and Jest websites.
I have run the tests through a jest script (`yarn test`) and `detox test`.

```
$ detox test --loglevel trace
detox[51199] INFO:  [test.js] configuration="ios.sim" loglevel="trace" artifactsLocation="artifacts/ios.sim.2019-04-26 12-31-53Z" recordLogs="none" takeScreenshots="manual" recordVideos="none" recordPerformance="none" node_modules/.bin/jest --config=e2e/config.json --maxWorkers=1 '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' "e2e"
● Validation Warning:

  Unknown option "setupFilesAfterEnv" with value ["./init.js"] was found.
  This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html

 FAIL  e2e/features/login/index.spec.js
  App
    ✕ should have login screen (272ms)
    ✕ should show hello screen after tap (104ms)
    ✕ should show world screen after tap (105ms)

  ● App › should have login screen

    ReferenceError: device is not defined

      at reloadApp (../node_modules/detox-expo-helpers/index.js:68:3)

  ● App › should have login screen

    ReferenceError: element is not defined
...
```

setupFilesAfterEnv *is* a jest option.

The downloaded Expo IPA is in the directory bin/Exponent.app.

package.json

```
{
...
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --notify",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "ci": "yarn lint && jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.1",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "detox": "^12.4.1",
    "detox-expo-helpers": "^0.6.0",
    "eslint": "^5.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "expo-detox-hook": "^1.0.10",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "react-native-testing-library": "^1.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "clearMocks": true
  },
  "detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "runner-config": "e2e/config.json",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim": {
        "binaryPath": "bin/Exponent.app",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone XR"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The e2e directory is straight from Detox with a few changes for Expo.

e2e/config.json

```
{
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./init.js"],
    "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

e2e/init.js

```
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');

jest.setTimeout(120000);
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);

beforeAll(async () => {
    await detox.init(config);
});

beforeEach(async () => {
    await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
    await adapter.afterAll();
    await detox.cleanup();
});
```

login.spec.js

```
import { reloadApp } from 'detox-expo-helpers';

describe('App', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await reloadApp();
    });

    it('should have login screen', async () => {
        await expect(element(by.id('login'))).toBeVisible();
    });

    it('should show hello screen after tap', async () => {
        await element(by.id('hello_button')).tap();
        await expect(element(by.text('Hello!!!'))).toBeVisible();
    });

    it('should show world screen after tap', async () => {
        await element(by.id('world_button')).tap();
        await expect(element(by.text('World!!!'))).toBeVisible();
    });
});
```

On a side note, I don't know why there is the jasmine reference in init.js. I guess it is because JestJS is based on Jasmine. Anyway, it does not seem to be connected with the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Summary

There is an [open pull-request](https://github.com/expo/detox-expo-helpers/pull/12) for this issue. I quote [`Yaron Malim`](https://github.com/yaron1m)

```
ReferenceError: device is not defined

  at Object.reloadApp (../node_modules/detox-expo-helpers/index.js:68:3)
```

> When I added the following require:

```
const { device } = require('detox');
```

> The issue was solved.
>   In order to do so, I had to add detox as a dependency. This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "detox-expo-helpers",
  "version": "0.6.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "detox": "^12.2.0",
    "semver": "^5.6.0",
    "xdl": "^51.5.0"
  }
}
```

Details of the [committed files in the pull request](https://github.com/expo/detox-expo-helpers/pull/12/files/57122590bbe5abf00a826daf3fe13621fffb5313)

### Installing the Necessaries Dependencies

The [`detox-expo-helpers` github repo](https://github.com/expo/detox-expo-helpers) includes [an example app](https://github.com/expo/with-detox-tests). Add [`expo-detox-hook` to your `package.json`](https://github.com/expo/with-detox-tests/blob/master/package.json#L19) and run `npm install`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "detox": "^9.0.6",
    "detox-expo-helpers": "^0.6.0",
    "expo-detox-hook": "^1.0.10",
    "mocha": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim": {
        "binaryPath": "bin/Exponent.app",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 7"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As explained on the [official `detox-expo-helpers` page](https://github.com/expo/detox-expo-helpers#set-up-detox-on-your-project) you should follow every step [to set up your `detox` project](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md), except for [the `package.json` configurations included in this step](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md#3-add-detox-config-to-packagejson), which are different in `expo`.

The `detox-expo-helpers` includes the official configuration for your emulator [at the step **Download the Expo app to some directory in your project and configure in `package.json`**](https://github.com/expo/detox-expo-helpers#download-the-expo-app-to-some-directory-in-your-project-and-configure-in-packagejson).

It also includes an [**example** of the `Detox` settings for your `package.json`](https://github.com/expo/with-detox-tests/blob/033020b165452d641f512a9b1a8a291632ce8e8f/package.json#L21-L29)

Your second test fails because `Detox` does not find the element on the page.
You need to pass a `testID` prop to the component with value `'hello_button'`.

```
it('should show hello screen after tap', async () => {
    await element(by.id('hello_button')).tap();
    await expect(element(by.text('Hello!!!'))).toBeVisible();
});
```

[documentation on `by.id` matcher](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Matchers.md#byidid)

> `by.id` will match an id that is given to the view via `testID` prop.

Your component should look like

```
<TouchableOpacity testID={'hello_button'}>
```

Comment: Added `expo-detox-hooks`, read all the the docs and double-checked them with my configuration, dumped and reloaded the node_modules, but I get exactly the same error(s).

Comment: @PaulB unluckily I don't know how to trouble shoot this issue. Did you try something else or have an update for me? thanks

Comment: Nothing I have done has made any difference.If you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot, I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: @PaulB I found the solution to your problem. You need to follow the instructions from this pull request https://github.com/expo/detox-expo-helpers/pull/12

Comment: The PR you mention definitely targets the source of the problem, but, unfortunately, just causes new errors. I will go ahead and accept the answer and hope that that someone (smarter than I) can get the PR to work.

Comment: After using:  const { device } = require('detox');, error that comes is: reloadReactNative is not a function. That means the import is wrong. and device is Alias of Device is also reported.